# Any function escaping a string for literal LIKE search?

Tags: sql, oracle

I noticed that performance for a filter in Oracle can be very different depending on whether you write

```
WHERE col LIKE 'abc%'
```

or

```
WHERE SUBSTR(col,1,3) = 'abc'
```

So, I would like to always use LIKE queries. But my prefix can contain any ASCII character, and thus I have to escape `%`, `_`, and the escape character itself.

- I could use a regexp_replace for anything like that:

  ```
  WHERE col LIKE REGEXP_REPLACE(pat, '([%_\\])', '\\\1') || '%' ESCAPE '\'
  ```
- I could also do a triple REPLACE:

  ```
  WHERE col LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(pat,'\','\\'),'%','\%'),'_','\_') || '%' ESCAPE '\'
  ```

Both ways are painful for the guy that will read it afterwards. Is there an alternative function, in the style of `WHERE begins_with(col, pat) > 0`, or `WHERE col LIKE like_literal(pat) || '%'` or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: `pat` seems to be coming from somewhere else.  Modify it before passing it into the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine your own escape character.

```
WHERE col LIKE 'A\_B%' ESCAPE '\';
```

In the pattern, the escape character precedes the underscore (_). This causes Oracle to interpret the underscore literally, rather than as a special pattern matching character.

Please read following link
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

Comment: Did you mean `WHERE col LIKE 'A\_B%' ESCAPE '\';`?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, yes he did, it was a markdown indentation issue

Comment: I already know that the escape character can be chosen. My issue is to know whether there is a convenient function to properly escape a literal string if I want to remove any special meaning for `%` and `_` without unrolling my own triple replace or regexp replace.